# Drupal: re-use same CCK Field in the same content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need a sequence of text, image, video CCK fields, repeated twice in my content type.
I need to create 2 different groups (I don't want to use multi-upload functionality).

I was wondering if I have to create a new field Image - File Upload for the second group, or I can somehow to re-use the first one (which is already added, and I would like to add it twice in the second group as well).

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved by creating 3 groups, and creating image1, image2, image3... video1, video2, video3, and text1, text2, text3 CCK fields. Any order is now possible.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Content Copy module from CCK package. It provides CCK fields import/export functionality.

Comment: At the label "Import", it says: "Note that fields cannot be duplicated within the same content type, so imported fields will be added only if they do not already exist in the selected type." So basically I cannot use duplicates (i.e. i've to create a new field_image2 if I want 2 image fields. Conseguently, I guess the easiest solution is to simcply create other 3 fields and add them to my content-type without using any other module...